# Postgresql.conf still retains ".sample" in filename?

Tags: macos, postgresql

I'm running Postgresql on Mac OSX by way of a Docker container image to launch my web application. My goal was to use a PersistentManager to store session data to a database.

After turning up the debug logs to see why the session information was not saving to the table I created, I noted the following error in the logs:

```
SEVERE: A SQL exception occurred org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:      Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

This led me to check postgresql.conf in /usr/local/share/postgresql to enable the correct TCP/IP listening. However, I was surprised to see that, instead of being called simply "postgresql.conf", it and many other files had a ".sample" at the end. They are the only versions of postgresql.conf according to my locate command. What's the cause of this? Do I need to perform a restart/reinstallation of the server?

Comment: Use the `SHOW config_file;` command (i.e. inside a `psql` session) to find where your true postgresql.conf file is used. It shouldn't be the .sample file, unless you're using an unusual Postgres package.

Comment: I installed via Homebrew and am running using the Pgadmin III graphical user interface - could that have anything to do with it? From bash, SHOW config_file; doesn't give me a result.

postgres=# SHOW config_file
postgres=#

Comment: Looks like you may have missed the trailing semicolon? `SHOW config_file;` should absolutely give you a result.

Comment: Thanks! I have no idea what happened - I realized I missed the semicolon and tried again, but no commands were returning any input. I closed the terminal tab and tried again, and it worked out. I appreciate the help! Turns out is located here: /usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf